# Stop multiple animations untill another animation gets completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Stop multiple animations while clicking button multiple times untill animation gets completed with the help of following code.
Declare one global variable

```
var animateFinish = true;
```

And here I am starting with click action

```
$('#button').on('click', function(e){
    if(animateFinish){
        animateFinish = false;
        $('.selector').animate({'margin-left':'100px'},"fast",'linear',function(){  
             animateFinish = true;
        }
    }  
}
```

1. Globally declare a variable as True (animateFinish).
2. First time it satisfies the condtion.
3. Immediately it is modified as false.
4. After completing animation it gets reverted.
5. Now, if you check it, till the animation gets completed event will not animated.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: The above code is working fine for my logic

Comment: I actually think you should potentially try to `stop()` any ongoing animation instead of delaying others. `stop()` will get rid of ongoing animations and start from there. If you want to chain animation, you do not need the animateFinish as you have a callback. You could create a qeue of functions and see if there is still one left to execute after every animate callback. Check out `queue()`: http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Comment: queue() is not working as per my requirements

Answer (score 0):

Personally, in your case, I might go with a global variable `var busy = false`, then add this on your click: `if(busy) return; else busy = true;`. At the end of your animation, set `busy` to `false`. That will prevent your click from doing anything until everything is completed.

Heres a quick snippet that shows what I mean:

```js
/* I use each here so that `busy` is only applied to each div individually.
 * That way every individual element has it's own `busy`. */
$("div").each(function(){
    var busy = false;
    $(this).click(function(){
        /* Abort the click operation if busy is active*/
        if(busy) return; else busy = true;
        /* Run the animation and deactivate busy on callback. */
        $(this).animate({left: 500}, 2000).animate({left:0}, 2000, function(){
            busy = false;
        });
    });
});
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top:0;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Click me!</div>
```

Comment: This code is good enough. But my scenario is like, I have a content slider which contains around 23 panels/boxes(not fixed. it's dynamic in my case). If a user clicks on next button, have to move 1panel box to the left side by its width. The problem is, if the user continuesly clicks on next button the animation effects differs so that i will have to make the user wait till the animation gets completed. So, i have implemented like the above.

Comment: @RanjithReddyKeesari If you move the `busy` outside of the `each` it will be global and count for every one of your boxes, if that makes sense. Sorry, this is the solution to the best of my understanding of your problem :)